# Проблема с логикой игры Крестики-Нолики

Tags: java, ооп, проектирование

Игра ХО.
Весь код [ХО](https://gist.github.com/EugeneWenew/9cb42f37b40fe7dc17ca9d6cd7b72615)

Ожидание:

> Метод doShoot класса GameController выбирает из двух игроков кто ходит
> следующим.

Текущая ситуация:

> Ходит всегда игрок с именем "Х".

```
public class GameController {
Field field;
Player player;

 public GameController(Field field, Player player) {
    this.field = field;
    this.player = player;
}

public void doShoot(Point point, Field.CellSign sign) {
    if (this.player.playerName == "X") {
        player.setPlayerCell(point);

    } else {
        this.player = field.players.get(1);
        player.setPlayerCell(field.getCompCell());


      }
        player.setIsShoot(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте this.player.playerName.equals("X")

Comment: почему вы решили, что проблема именно с использованием this?

Comment: Игра плохо спроектирована. Не удивительно, что ходит все время `Х` (видимо один раз) `getWindowCell() { isShoot = false;  while (!isShoot); return point; }` Очень много ошибок. Начинать надо с блок-схемы, то есть логики

Comment: @AlexanderChernin во-первых игра никак не спроектирована. Нет у меня такого образования и таких знаний. Как считал нужным так и делал. Во-вторых помогите мне не своей структурой программы, а доделать то, что я почти сделал. В моем коде загвоздка с методом doShoot. Не работает проверка текущего игрока. Как исправить?